# mysql join results in a field having zeros in every row of resultset

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to join two tables like this...

```
SELECT * FROM lists l
INNER JOIN products p USING (list_id)
```

Here is the `show create table` for both the tables..

```
CREATE TABLE `lists` (
  `list_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
  PRIMARY KEY (`list_id`),
  KEY `index1` (`list_name`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `list_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`),
  KEY `index2` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here's the result of above query:

l.list_id : l.list_name : l.deleted : p.product_id : p.deleted

```
1   Christmas   0   1   1
1   Christmas   0   2   0
1   Christmas   0   3   0
1   Christmas   0   4   0
4   New Year    0   8   0
4   New Year    0   9   0
4   New Year    0   10  0
```

You see `l.deleted` column there with all zeros? In the table `lists` there are some rows with other values like 1, 2, ... in `deleted` column. But joining the tables always show the `deleted` column to have all zeros.

Why is this happening? What am I missing here?

Comment: is this entire result set for the query? If so, then it means list 1 and 4 are not deleted and list 2,3 (if they exist) don't have products related to them thus they don't show in the result set. Can you create your tables and dataset in [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) and share the link here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a different syntax to express your `JOIN`.  If you use the `ON` syntax, you'll have more clarity about what is joining to what.  This is stylistic.

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM lists l
INNER JOIN products p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
```

But, I suspect you have items in your `lists` table (with `deleted` column values that aren't zero, that aren't turning up in your `products` table.  To see those in your result set try this:

```
SELECT * FROM lists l
LEFT JOIN products p ON l.list_id = p.list_id
```